# DI-524 router, I cannot set the time past December 31, 2012

Tags: wireless-router, clock

is there any patch or download that will enable me to keep using my DI-524 router? I did a factory reset in December 2012, which caused it to revert to a date in 2005, as there is no internal clock on the device. I am unable to reset the time manually because the drop-down choices do not go past Dec. 31, 2012, and I am not getting a response when selecting the NTP option. Is my router  completely obsolete? help?

Comment: Waht version of the firmware is installed on the router?  Have you tried the latest version?

Comment: Does it even matter that its time is set correctly? I doubt it.

Comment: @Tom Wijsman  Unless he monitors the logs?

Comment: @TomWijsman Bad dates could lead to DHCP lease issues and (maybe?) problems with wireless encryption.

Comment: @K.A: Could you please explain why? Both do not share time or date in their protocol, just offsets.

Comment: @Tog: Not a problem since it's only the year that's off, it's a SOHO anyway...

Comment: @TomWijsman Don't DHCP servers lease IPs and specify when they have to be renewed? What ifthe server said an IP lease was to be renewed at some date that the client thought was in the past? That is my understanding of the protocol.

Comment: @K.A: That's not true, you should read up on the protocol; DHCP does not tell you "at some date", it tells you "in X seconds from now". It does not send any date or time information...

Comment: @TomWijsman Interesting. You will have to ask the original poster their particular reasons then.

Comment: @K.A.: For reference, page 37 of [RFC 2131](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) mentions `The client records the lease expiration time as the sum of the time at which the original request was sent and the duration of the lease from the DHCPACK message.`

Answer (score 1):

If NTP is not working, I would say your only real option is to make sure the firmware is updated by looking at the D-Link site for your router: http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/product/di-524-high-speed-2-4ghz-802-11g-wireless-router?revision=

If not, it appears that you will have to put up with perennially incorrect dates on your router since D-Link has stopped supporting this model. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have the same router, I have no way of telling if it will help, but you should try to upgrade the firmware.

If you take a look at the backside of your router, you should see the revision (H/W Ver.) and the factory-installed firmware (F/W Ver.):

[image: photo]

Once you know your router's revision, go to the [DI-524 support page](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/product/di-524-high-speed-2-4ghz-802-11g-wireless-router), select the proper revision and click **Select**.

This will give you access to the latest firmware. Compare the latest version to the factory-installed one. If it differs, download the firmware and follow the remaining steps outlined in [How do I upgrade the firmware on my DI series router?](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/faqs/routers/wireless-routers/di-series/how-do-i-upgrade-the-firmware-on-my-di-series-router):

1. Open the web-based router configuration.
2. Click on the **Tools** tab and then the **Firmware** button on the left side. Click on the **Browse** button and browse to the .bin (or .dlf) file you downloaded. Highlight the file by clicking on it once and click **Open**.
3. Click **Apply**, wait for the upgrade to complete, then click **Continue** button.

Do this from a wired connection. If your WiFi connection drops during the upgrade, your router might become unusable.

If this doesn't help (or your router already has the latest firmware, you're out of luck. The model has been phased out in 2008 and support ended in 2009...